# Shell script returns 0 exit_status despite syntax error

Tags: shell, exit-status, dash

Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

foo=1
if [[ ! -z $foo ]]; then
    echo abc
fi
```

It's using the Bash syntax [[ ... ]] which doesn't work (as expected) when I run it with the default shell on Ubuntu (dash). However, its return code is still zero.

```
$ ./tmp.sh
./tmp.sh: 4: ./tmp.sh: [[: not found
$ echo $?
0
```

How can I detect this kind of error in a script if I can't rely on the exit code?

Comment: That's not a *syntax* error.

Comment: Are you primarily thinking about scripts written by you (that you can modify), or about scripts that you may be not able/not willing/not allowed to modify?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me first explain why this happens. [POSIX Shell Command Language
spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)
says:

> The exit status of the if command shall be the exit status of the then
> or else compound-list that was executed, or zero, if none was
> executed.

Since in your case `then` part is not executed and there is no `else`
the exit status is 0. It would also be 0 if you ran this script using
Bash as in `man bash` it says:

```
   if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi

          The if list is executed.  If its exit status is zero,
          the then list is executed.  Otherwise, each elif list is
          executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the
          corresponding then list is executed and the command
          completes.  Otherwise, the else list is executed, if
          present.  The exit status is the exit sta‐ tus of the
          last command executed, or zero if no condition tested
          true.
```

> How can I detect this kind of error in a script if I can't rely on the exit code?

There are 2 ways I could think of:

- if you can modify your script add `else` part to the if construct:

  ```
    #!/bin/sh

    foo=1
    if [[ ! -z $foo ]]; then
        echo abc
    else
        echo not true
        exit 1
    fi
  ```
- if you got if from someone and you're not willing to modify it use
  shellcheck static analyzer in `sh` mode to look for possible bugs in
  the code and report them to the author:

  ```
    $ shellcheck -s sh dash-exit-status.sh

    In dash-exit-status.sh line 4:
    if [[ ! -z $foo ]]; then
       ^-------------^ SC2039: In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined.
          ^-- SC2236: Use -n instead of ! -z.

    For more information:
      https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2039 -- In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined.
      https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2236 -- Use -n instead of ! -z.
  ```

Basically, this is a *bug* to me as one should not use non-POSIX
features in scripts that are supposed to be executed by `/bin/sh`
which might but doesn't have to be a symlink to Bash.

Answer (score 5):

Note that as @muru commented, that's not a syntax error as far as Dash is concerned. `[` is not a special character to the shell in the way `;` and `(` are. `[` is just a regular command like `echo`, only with a funny name. In Bash/Ksh/Zsh `[[` is a keyword like `if`, and  keywords are part of the shell syntax, but crucially, in shells that *don't* support it, `[[` would be treated as just another command.

Since Dash doesn't support `[[`, it's looked for in the `PATH` as any other command, and the lookup fails. As the [answer by Arkadiusz Drabczyk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/650948/170373) says, the result here is an exit status of zero. If it was an actual syntax error, the shell would exit immediately with a non-zero status.

> How can I detect this kind of error in a script if I can't rely on the exit code?

Well, technically, you could...

```
#!/bin/dash
[[ $1 == "foo" ]]
case $? in
    0)    echo "the first argument was 'foo'";;
    1)    echo "the first argument was something else";;
    127)  echo "[[ not supported";;
    *)    echo "there was some other error";;
esac
```

Or the same with `ret=$?` and a chain of `if-elif` with conditions against `$ret`. That's somewhat awkward to do, and not the best solution here, but if you really need to tell apart different error codes of some command, that's what you have to do.

If you're aiming at detecting the Dash vs. Bash case in particular, you could add an extra test at the start of the script to see if `[[` works correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [[ a == a ]] 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "[[ not supported, exiting." >&2
    exit 1
fi

# ...
```

Similarly, you could probably add tests for all other non-POSIX features you use, but testing them *all* can of course get a bit unwieldy.

To demand exactly Bash, and not just any shell that has the same features (Ksh and Zsh are compatible with some stuff, though not with all), check `$BASH_VERSION` at the start of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    echo "Running only with Bash supported, exiting" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# ...
```

(The variable can of course be set manually, but than the user better know what they're doing.)

Comment: `check $BASH_VERSION at the start of the script` - if the script _has to_ be run with Bash shouldn't changing the shebang be suggested too? One can easily fake that they're using Bash by setting `BASH_VERSION` environment variable.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, yep, the hashbang should indeed be set. Sure, the environment variable can be faked, but if someone does that, then they probably know what they're doing or at least deserve to pick up the pieces if something breaks...

Comment: Thanks for elaborating more on the distinction between syntax and commands

Comment: @vitalstatistix, on a second look, that paragraph wasn't too well written. For Bash, a broken `[[` would be a syntax error, the same way as a broken `if` construct would be. `if ! [[; then echo hmm; fi` is a syntax error in Bash; but not in Dash where it's just a regular command-not-found, which doesn't stop the rest of the script from running. Of _course_ keywords are part of syntax, whatever the guy in the answer first said. (There's some difference between _keywords_ like `[[` or `if` and _operators_ like `(` or `;`, though.)